# Check whether column has an input string that has already been inserted

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and faced with a problem where I have two columns. Column 1 has a job description and the other has a job number.

The user inputs a job description in column 1 and in column 2 an automatic job number is given. I created vba code that asks the user for a job description and creates a job number for that input. I want to create a function where if the user types in the same job description in a row below it the job number keeps the same number but gets a letter added to it. So if there 5 of the same job descriptions the numbers would go from 01, 01A, 01B, 01C and 01D.

I tried creating a function that searches for the userinput and the goes to the next search. If that the activecell equals the user input then add a count to the job number. But with letters.

```
Dim prompt as integer
Dim userinput as string
Dim userinputjobnum as variant

prompt = InputBox("Select a row you would like to work in")
userinput = InputBox("Job description?", "Description")
Cells(prompt, 1).Value = userinput


Cells.Find(What:=userinput, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

If ActiveCell.Value = userinput Then
userinputjobnum = ??
Cells(prompt,2).value = userinputjobnum
End if
```

Comment: Look into using a scripting Dictionary.

Comment: I'd try figuring out how to do a VBA version of formula function `COUNTIF(A:A, userinput & "*")` and then, if that value was greater than 0, return a VBA version of formula function `CHAR(64+count)` (which breaks after count is greater than 26 but at least it would be enough for a proof of concept)

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Thanks so much !!